# How to make AdSense Auto Ads work with Gatsby

Tags: adsense, gatsby

I've been using AdSense Auto Ads on my server-side rendered PHP-based framework with great success for a while now.

But now I'm moving to JAMStack and I have a Gatsby site. Obviously, when client-side rendering is involved, Auto Ads are not working as I expected.

Is there a way to trigger Auto Ads to run after a page mounts in Gatsby? As is the case with Auto Ads, I don't really have any ad placements on my site, so no  tags anywhere. I just let Auto Ads do their jobs.

Is that possible with Gatsby as well?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this without gatsby but with Google Tag Manager.
Basically, you need to create a trigger on page changes. 
The trigger Type is "History Change".
Then create Auto Ads script tag, then on Triggering section, choose the history trigger you just created above.

Alternatively: 
 Add this to your react-helmet component or on html.js file

```
     <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
              google_ad_client: "id",
              enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
            `,
          }}
 />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I did what you suggested first - added the AdSense code to GTM and added the History Change trigger. It works, I can see that the AdSense script loads every time the page changes, as it should. But this produces an error: AdSense says that enable_page_level_ads should only be set once per page. So I decided to do that: only .push() the enable_page_level_ads property on the first load and let AdSense take care of the rest. As you can expect, it didn't quite work. All it did was load the ads for the first pageview perfectly, but load no ads for subsequent pageviews.

Comment: I think Auto Ads is simply not meant for client-side rendered pages and client-side navigation. That's very unfortunate that it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that even with regular, manually <ins>erted fluid ad placements, it causes errors. Even though the adsbygoogle.push() only happens on componentDidMount, it produces a white screen of death, like it always happens when you call document.write outside of the DOM context.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was to not use Gatsby's internal router at all. I need server-side rendering in order for Auto Ads to work, so there's not much else I could do.